# Why does C# compiler thinks this nullabale reference can be null?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I have this code where the compiler says that `myObj` in `ValidateMyObj(myObj)` may be null.
Since it *has* to be not-null for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to return `false` and enter the condition, how can it consider it could be null?

But most of all, how can it then consider that it cannot be null in `myObj.Exists`?

```
var myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj?.StrProp))
{
    ValidateMyObj(myObj);
    if (ViewBag.IsValid)
        myObj.Exists = true;
}
```

**Edit: Playing with explicit null-check**

Simply adding the explicit null-check gives the same behaviour:

```
var myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);
if (myObj != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj?.StrProp))
{
    ValidateMyObj(myObj);
    if (ViewBag.IsValid)
        myObj.Exists = true;
}
```

this compiles to (according to the ILSpy decompiler when deactivating the decompilation of the `?` operator)

```
MyObjType myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);
if (myObj != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty((myObj != null) ? myObj.StrProp : null))
{
    ValidateMyObj(myObj);
    if (ViewBag.IsValid)
        myObj.Exists = true;
}
```

On the other hand, if I then remove the null-conditional operator, then the squiggly line disapears.

```
var myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);
if (myObj != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj.StrProp))
{
    ValidateMyObj(myObj);
    if (ViewBag.IsValid)
        myObj.Exists = true;
}
```

In fact, it also disapears if I remove the explicit check *and* the null-conditional operator nor does it give one on the argument passed to ÌsNullOrEmpty`:

```
var myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj.StrProp))
{
    ValidateMyObj(myObj);
    if (ViewBag.IsValid)
        myObj.Exists = true;
}
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is only annotated for what's passed to it, so it only knows that `myObj?.StrProp` is not null. *You* know that to be true, but the compiler doesn't do the analysis that would enable it to know that.

Comment: A pattern-matching way of writing this that satisfies the null checks at the same time is `if (myObj is { StrProp: string { Length: > 0 } })`. Whether you like that sort of thing is up to personal preference.

Comment: It helps to remember that null checking is part of the C# spec. It's not just a matter of Microsoft programming their compiler to be smart enough to know what will be null: they have to embody the logic into the C# language spec in a simple enough way that _every_ C# compiler can get it right. So there are several things like this that a compiler _could_ be made to infer, but which they don't bother to include because it would add too much complexity to the language specification.

Comment: You've uncovered an interesting nuance of nullability analysis: `if (myObj != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj?.StrProp))` tells the compiler that you now expect that `myObj` might be `null` after all and so negates the previous null check. As nullability checks are intended to do, this reveals an error in your assumptions, so that's a good thing.

Comment: However, I'm confused about the last one. You assign `myObj` to something that could be `null`, as `FirstOrDefault` is perfectly capable of returning `null`... it should give you the "possibly null reference" warning when you access `myObj.StrProp`. As for the decompilation, the nullability analysis is on the `?.` operator, at compile time, not the ternary that ILSpy gave you, so that's kind of a red herring.

Comment: @madreflection I don't think that's true that it *negates* the previous check, I think it's just that once you use a value without a null check, you are effectively saying "can't move past here with a null" because otherwise you would have a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: @Charlieface: Does [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y4KEht) change anything for you?

Comment: @Charlieface: It [gets worse](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KWOVj3). When a variable that was declared non-nullable and was initialized to an instance is subsequently dereferenced with `?.`, it becomes nullable to the analyzer. The lesson here is not to use `?.` when it's not necessary.

Comment: @madreflection IMO that's a bug in the analyzer as it should be pretty obvious. Or maybe I'm just used to using Resharper, I don't think it does that. Then again, I live dangerously (I don't usually bother with `nullable enable` because too many unnecessary warnings) so probably misremembering

Comment: @Charlieface: I see your point, and maybe Resharper goes deeper (I don't use it because I find it intrusive in so many other ways), but I don't agree that it's a bug. If you know it's not null in a certain context, why would you think you need to use `?.` on it? The compiler probably could *do better* to tell you that you don't need it there rather than reset it to a nullable state and give the warning later, and that's what I opine it should do, if it were to do anything different in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null-state analysis of the C# compiler tries to keep track of the null-state of every variable based on the context where it is used.

The null-state might be:

1. The value is known to be null.
2. The value is known to be not null.
3. The null-state is unknown (maybe-null).

After the assignment `var myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);` myObj is in the *maybe-null* state (this actually depends on the framework – see below).

The call to `string.IsNullOrEmpty` doesn't change the null-state. The `string.IsNullOrEmpty` method is just an ordinary method. Without extra knowledge the compiler doesn't know anything about the null-state of the parameter.

It turns out that in .NET 6 the compiler gets this extra help. In .NET 6 the signature of that method is:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty([NotNullWhen(false)] string? value);
```

In .NET Framework however the signature is:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string value);
```

The `NotNullWhen` attribute tells the compiler that the argument passed to `string.IsNullOrEmpty` is not null when the method returns false. Therefore in .NET 6 you don't get any warnings in your original code because the compiler changes the null-state to *not-null* inside the if-block. In .NET Framework 4.8 (or earlier) it can't do that so the null-state inside the if-block is the same as outside.

Surprisingly after adding the explicit null check for `myObj` the squiggly line doesn't go away.

```
if (myObj != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj?.StrProp)) { ... }
```

is equivalent to

```
if (myObj != null)
{
    // null-state of myObj is not-null
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj != null ? myObj.StrProp : null))
    {
        // the second test changed the null-state of myObj to maybe-null
    }
}
```

When you now remove that second test the null-state doesn't change and the warning goes away.

---

The framework also influences how the return value of the `FirstOrDefault` method is treated.

Right at the beginning you have:

```
var myObj = myObjCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Member);`
```

Obviously this should set `myObj` to the *maybe-null* state and should give a warning when you then dereference the variable without checking for null:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj.StrProp)) { ... } // should warn: Dereference of a pssibly null reference
```

It seems that it doesn't do that when you are on .NET Framework. But it does when you are on .NET 6.

This can be explained when you look at the history of C# and .NET.
C# 8 was the first version to support nullable reference types. It was released shortly **after** the last version of .NET Framework (4.8).

In .NET Framework the signature is:

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

In .NET 6 it is:

```
public static TSource? FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

This means that the nullability context is unclear when you call `FirstOrDefault<T>` on .NET Framework but it is clear on .NET 6.

As far as I am aware the C# compiler team has decided not to warn when the context is unclear because that would give too many false warnings and would annoy too many people.

Having said that: If you want more reliable nullability analysis you should use a version of the framework which is fully null-aware.

Answer (score 2):

If I got this right then i think it is because the `IsNullOrEmpty` is refering to the `StrProp` but the warning targets the `myObj`

Clarification:
if `myObj` is null then there isn't a `StrProp` to check for